# link not working in fancybox caption

Tags: jquery, fancybox, lightbox

I using the fancybox plugin for jquery and I want to put a link in the title attribute (image caption). The link displays just fine but does nothing with I click on it.

```
$('.lightbox').fancybox({
    'titlePosition' : 'inside'
});
```

HTML:

```
<a href='pathtoimage.jpg' title="text about the project :: <a href='http://www.someclient.com'>Launch website</a> " class='lightbox' >
    <img src="pathtoimage.jpg" alt="clientname" />
</a>
```

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

The problem was with some other javascript on my site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works, maybe the **'quotes'** should be double quotes.

I have:

```
<a class="gallery" href="delete/big.png" title="text about the project :: <a href='http://www.someclient.com'>Launch website</a>"><img src="delete/thumb.png" width="115" height="115" alt="" /></a>

$('a.gallery').fancybox({
    'titlePosition' : 'inside'
});
```

And it works.

Comment: I just tried it in the fancybox demo by changing some of the text in the caption to a link. and you're right it does work. must be something weird with my page then. not really sure how to proceed though...

Comment: You can upload it somewhere, or use pastebin.com. (if it's already online post the link) So we can take a look.

Comment: http://www.maxqdesigns.com/portfolio/web_design/test - really appreciate the help. If it's not too much trouble, could you also let me know how you found the problem so I can learn from this. Thanks!

Comment: You have some links without href attribute set in the page so you can first try to add href="javascript: void(0);" to these. BTW, I don't see the point on using <a></a> in there.

Comment: I don't either. I didn't make this site. I'm just one of the designers here. I took out the empty a tags. Didn't seem to have an affect.

Comment: The code there, is really messed up... Sorry but "I can't" read it.

Comment: I figured it out. It was some other javascript checking all links for 404's. Thanks again.